# Help with coding a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with a full set of eigenvalues $\lambda$ including repetitions.

I want to create the following $i \times i$ matrix:

$$\left(\sum_{a=2}^i (a-1) |a-1⟩⟨a| \right) + \sum_{j=1}^i d_j 
 \sum_{b=j}^i |b⟩⟨b-j+1| $$

where $|1⟩,...,|i⟩$ is the standard basis and  $d_j (\lambda) = \sum_{c=1}^n \lambda_c^j$.

Any help with coding this matrix in Mathematica would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must give an explicit mathematical formula for $|b \rangle \langle b-j+1|$ and other terms.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I added a missing definition and believe I have defined all the other terms. Please let me know if any definition is unclear.

Comment: The first term $\delta_{i,0}$ is a scalar, not a matrix, and does not fit into the formula. Does it mean that for $i=0$ you want to get the scalar 1 as the answer?

Comment: Does $d_j(\lambda)$ depend on $j$ at all?

Comment: @Roman Thanks for your comments. I had mistakenly written the superscript of $x$ as $q$ instead of $j$. $\delta_{i,0}$ would be the identity matrix when $i=0$, which makes this term irrelevant now that I think about it. Sorry for the mistake with the definition of $d_j$ and thanks for spotting out the unnecessary $\delta_{i,0}$ factor. I have edited my question to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the matrix with

```
M[1] = {{d[1]}};
M[i_Integer /; i >= 2] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> Range[i - 1],
                                       {a_, b_} /; a >= b -> d[a - b + 1]},
                                      {i, i}]
```

With the $d$-elements

```
λ = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
d[j_] = Total[λ^j];
```

(replace the $\lambda$-vector by your eigenvalues).

```
M[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a combination of [`ToeplitzMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToeplitzMatrix.html), [`DiagonalMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html), [`LowerTriangularize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LowerTriangularize.html) and [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
ClearAll[mat]
mat[n_] := Module[{dd = Array[d, n]}, 
  LowerTriangularize[ToeplitzMatrix[dd, SparseArray]] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray@Range[n - 1], 1]]

mat[5] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  d(1) & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  d(2) & d(1) & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
>  d(3) & d(2) & d(1) & 3 & 0 \\
>  d(4) & d(3) & d(2) & d(1) & 4 \\
>  d(5) & d(4) & d(3) & d(2) & d(1) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: This can be simplified quite a bit, and can be arranged such that the output is a `SparseArray[]`: `mat[n_Integer /; n > 1] := ToeplitzMatrix[Array[d, n], PadRight[{d[1]}, n], SparseArray] + DiagonalMatrix[Range[n - 1], 1, n, SparseArray]`